# Selenium PDF Parser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pdfbox

In my application I will land in one page there will be a text in there and I have to open a PDF in the same page and compare the text in the PDF and the main page matches.
I am using pdfbox -1.8.15

But when I run the below code getting this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 
>      Error: End-of-File, expected line at
>          org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1523) at
>          org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseHeader(PDFParser.java:372) at 
>          org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:186) at 
>          TestCases.lastpdf.main(lastpdf.java:83)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_cph_main_rg_QiSummaries_ctl00__0\"]/td[2]/img")).click();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    //Switch to child window
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
URL url = new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
System.out.println(url);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

String mypdftxt;
BufferedInputStream fileToParse = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream()); 

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(fileToParse);
parser.parse(); // exception occurs here

mypdftxt  = new PDFTextStripper().getText(parser.getPDDocument());

System.out.println(mypdftxt);
```

Comment: Pdf file which you are trying to open. Is it in the file system or in the web page?

Comment: Please save what you are getting in `url.openStream()` into a temp file to find out whether that is really a PDF file. And not a web page, or a redirection.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the full stack trace, and mention what line has the exception (I assume it is `parser.parse();` but I'd prefer to be sure)

Comment: @ Bhargav Marpu -  Thanks for the followup .The PDF is in the web page

Comment: @ Tilman Hausherr - Thanks for the followup. Yes the exception is in the parser.parse();

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1523)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseHeader(PDFParser.java:372)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:186)
 at TestCases.lastpdf.main(lastpdf.java:83)

Comment: Thank you, I've added the exception into the question. It confirms my suspicion that whatever you get with `url.openStream()` is empty. Check if the URL is correct, and whether you also get something empty when you do it manually. Also check the server logs, whether there is a difference there depending on how the URL is called.

Comment: Any update on this? If yes, comment, answer the question yourself, or delete the question.